# Remove and Direct all traffic through index.php from .htaccess to web.config in IIS10

Tags: .htaccess

Could someone please help me convert the following .htaccess file to web.config?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I tried to use Rewrite Module to translate it but it fails for the following:

1. `RewriteBase /` This is not supported in IIS
2. `RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]` IIS also fails to translate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one on Microsoft website. It works. Mufi's answer run URLs without index.php and with index.php too. This code below rewrite and remove index.php from URL.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect index.php" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="index\.php/(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Rewrite index.php">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Visit the following [link](https://forums.iis.net/t/1173705.aspx?Rewrite%20index%20php%20) for more info

Answer (score 0):

In web.config rewrite and remove index.php will work like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Visit this [URL](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) for more information.

Comment: Thank you.  This `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />` and `<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />`. Is there a way to make it read the URL from current visiting website instead of manually editing the link?

Comment: Nope, But you can ignore that part with little change. I have edited my answer. please try this updated code (Not tested by me [let me know if it not work out.])

Comment: It does not remove index.php automatically but when I type in something like `http://localhost/contact` instead of `http://localhost/index.php/contact` it still works.

Comment: Yes. htaccess is works like this. You run site without index.php not remove index.php.. that's a trick.

Comment: Sry I tried to edit the comment but it would not let me. What I meant was when we type in something like this `http://localhost/index.php/contact` a link with index.php. It should rewrite it to none index.php link but all traffic will need to direct through index.php if that makes sense.